# avd emulates wrong sdk

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to test my application in Android 6.0 (23 SDK).
But inside the code
`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` returns 22! not `Build.VERSION_CODES.M` 23!
So, `checkSelfPermission()` method gives `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`.
[image: this is screenshot for Android virual device]

Why? Is it a bug?

Comment: Which SDK version have you downloaded for API 23?

Comment: What is that warning at the bottom of the window?  Do you have everything installed as it suggests?

Comment: User31 is correct. Android Preview M is deprecated (and even restricted). Delete that AVD, then update your build-tools and update your sdks. Then try again. Also, check your build.gradle file for your application to make sure the target isn't set for 22.

Comment: These comments did not helped

Answer (score 0):

Has a similar problem last year and it was due to emulator being in preview version .of android M.
Can you try with a check of build.version.release.equals(M)

May be you are having the same problem with your emulator .see if it works

Comment: it returns 23, but avd starts as 22. in avd settings inside the devices it is shown as Android 5.1:(